# How to get an exclusive lock on a Postgres table using Ecto?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

How would I get a lock on an entire Postgres table, such that no other process can update any row in the table (but can still read rows with SELECT)?
I think the lock type I want is EXCLUSIVE, but I am not sure how do acquire such a lock for the entire table using an Ecto query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`LOCK`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-lock.html):

```
LOCK my_table IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

Note that `LOCK TABLE` can only be used in transaction blocks.

See also [How to use raw sql with ecto Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27751216/1995738)